# Legally, are you still obliged to serve your notice period even if you don't have any handover to do?

Tags: resignation, notice-period, france

Our company went to a PSE ( Plan de sauvegarde d'emploi). PSE in France is a way for companies to save their business by declaring that they are having some financial difficulties and they need to cut off or remove jobs. This is a very tedious process wherein the labor union and the company negotiates for the package of those leaving and the conditions of those staying and takes months normally for them to come to an agreement or not. But anyway, part of this plan is to have volunteers from the employees with certain requirements to leave the job. However the number of volunteers accepted should not exceed the number of posts/jobs to be removed.

After voluntary departure by substitution period, i found out that I am not part of the plan so I need to stay.

In my case, we didn't have any activity for 5 months now and no handover to do. But after I gave my resignation, the management insists that I need to do 3 months of notice period.

I have a new job waiting for me since 5 months ago. But now I am stucked and need to stay for another 3 months without doing anything.

Legally, speaking, is there a way for me to contest and not serve the 3 months notice period?

Comment: As this community has an international audience, can you provide some description on what a PSE is and how such plans work in France for non - French readers?

Comment: edited and added some description

Comment: @foreigner_in_france So to clarify, you wanted to leave but was not part of the plan. Then you proceeded to quit, is that right?

Comment: You cannot be sure you will be doing nothing for the next three months. As the employer reshuffles work based on who left, they may want the flexibility to assign you new tasks.

Comment: What does your contract say? If it doesn't specify exceptions, there's your answer.

Comment: Not the nicest way to play, but:  Step 1. call in sick for a week. Step 2. come back and ask them if they are willing to agree to let you go on short notice. If they still say no, repeat at step 1 ...

Comment: @DarkCygnus : Yes exactly, that's what happened.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Yes, that is their plan but since I already gave my resignation and I did'nt have any work for 5 months and nothing to handover, I dont find any logic for them to hold me for another 3 months

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that the availability of work will matter for whether they can enforce the contract. I can see some logic to insisting on notice in your situation. Your employer may not want employees who want to leave anyway trying for the PSE compensation rather than resigning. Requiring the full notice period from people resigning immediately after the PSE period may encourage others to resign more promptly.

Answer (score 4):

> Legally, speaking, is there a way for me to <s>not</s> contest and not serve the 3 months notice period?

Legally speaking you **have to serve the notice period you agreed on contract**, usually they are a two-week period, but this depends on each company and each contract.

Seems to me that you were hoping to be selected by the PSE to "gracefully" leave that company for other one you like better. By the way you describe it, it seems that this could have been a way to skip the notice period. But that is not possible now, and the PSE situation is now not useful in your current situation.

So, if you try to contest or fight for this I consider you have few chances of succeeding. Leaving without serving your period could have negative consequences for you and your career, so I recommend you give this proper consideration before chosing anything.

Comment: Only if the contract terms are legally enforceable. They're often not. There may, for example, be industrial relations laws in his country that mandate that notice periods cannot be that long. The poster would need to seek qualified legal advice.

Comment: The answer is partially correct, but not as complete as the French government website (in French): https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2883

Comment: Yes, I am debating on what could be the best action to take. I wonder if anyone knows of a government agency in France that can advice or help in my situation.

Comment: @foreigner_in_france probably a Lawyer that knows French Law could give you a more specific guidance here

Comment: @foreigner_in_france why not ask the trade union - they will have dealt with voluntary redundancy

Comment: In france they're usually 1 month or 3 month periods. As an engineer, all my notice period have been 3 months.

Comment: The two week period is country, region, and sometimes field specific. The rest of the answer is correct though: unless the law specifies a maximum notice period shorter than the one in the OP's contract, the contract's notice period applies.